Radon measure which is not outer regular with respect to open sets
I am trying to do Exercise 416Y (d) from Fremlin's "Measure theory vol 4. Topological measure spaces".
Thus, $X\subseteq \beta\mathbb{N}$ is the union of open sets $G\subseteq \beta\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n\in G\cap \mathbb{N}} \tfrac{1}{1+n}<+\infty$. Together with subspace topology, it is locally compact and Hausdorff. We define measure (on $\mathcal{P}(X)$) via $\mu(E)=\sum_{n\in E\cap \mathbb{N}}\tfrac{1}{1+n}$.
I was able to prove that $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite Radon measure (in the sense 411H). I however do not know how to show that $\mu$ is not outer regular wrt open sets (i.e. $\mu(E)=\inf \mu (G)$ with $\inf$ running over open sets $E\subseteq G\subseteq X$).
My approach was to show that the condition breaks down for $E=X\setminus \mathbb{N}$. This set has measure $0$, but I don't see how to deduce anything useful about open sets $E\subseteq G$.
Ideally I'm asking for a hint, not full solution.
PS. I'm using the ultrafilter construction of $\beta\mathbb{N}$.

Just to clarify, here Radon measures mean inner regular locally finite Borel measures?

Not quite. According to Fremlin's definition, Radon measure may be defined on a $\sigma$-algebra which contains Borel sets, but is possibly larger. Apart from that, one assumes that topology is Hausdorff, measure is complete, locally determined, locally finite and inner regular wrt compacts. That is a definition, but some stronger properties follow, e.g. measure is strictly localizable and $\tau$-additive. I think the reason for considering larger $\sigma$-algebra is to have Lebesgue measure as an example.

Locally determined? What does that mean? That is not among standard terminologies in measure theory nowadays.

It is definition 211H in 2nd Fremlin's book: measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is locally determined if it is semi-finite and $\Sigma={E\subseteq X,|, E\cap F\in \Sigma , for, all ,F\in \Sigma,\mu(F)<+\infty}$. This condition is in general weaker than being strictly localizable, but in the case of Radon measures one can replace "locally determined" by "strictly localizable".

I see. Pretty sure this is just equivalent to completions of inner regular locally finite Borel measures in case $X$ is LCH. (Though even that is not the usual definition of Radon measures nowadays.) But I suppose the author wants to be more general.

@DavidGao what would you consider to be the usual definition?

The most common definition for Radon measures nowadays is outer regular locally finite Borel measures which are inner regular on open sets (i.e., for an open $O$, $\mu(O) = \sup_K \mu(K)$ where $K$ ranges over compact subsets of $O$). This is not equivalent to inner regular locally finite Borel measures, and unlike inner regular locally finite Borel measures, they may not be strictly localizable. But it does have the added benefit of always being regular if the measure is $\sigma$-finite (as opposed to inner regular locally finite Borel measures, as the example in your question shows).

(Though for LCH spaces, while the two definitions are not equivalent, the Radon measures they define are in one-to-one correspondence with each other. Given an outer regular locally finite Borel measure which is inner regular on open sets, its semifinite part is an inner regular locally finite Borel measure. And given an inner regular locally finite Borel measure $\nu$, you can get a Radon measure in the usual sense by defining $\mu(A) = \inf_O \nu(O)$ where $O$ ranges over all open sets containing $A$.)

Thanks! This wealth of non-equivalent definitions is quite confusing to me... Anyway, I think I prefer Fremlin's definition as then Radon measures are strictly localizable and this property seems important to me, as in this case $L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$ is a von Neumann algebra. Do you know if the Radon measures according to the second definition (outer regular, locally finite, Borel, inner regular on open sets) are localizable?

Depending on what "localizable" means. Some people use localizable to mean what I think you are calling strictly localizable, in which case no. But if by localizable you mean there exists a partition ${X_\lambda}$, all of finite measure, s.t. a set $A$ is measurable iff $A \cap X_\lambda$ is measurable for all $\lambda$, and for a set $A$ with finite measure, $\mu(A) = \sum_\lambda \mu(A \cap X_\lambda)$, then yes, Radon measures according to the common definition (on an LCH space) would be localizable.

Personally, as a von Neumann algebraist, I also prefer being able to always say $L^\infty(X, \mu)$ is a vNa, but the outer regular definition is more common nowadays, presumably because being able to go from $\sigma$-finite to regular is more important from a measure theory point of view. Mostly, it doesn't really matter. For $\sigma$-compact LCH spaces the two definitions are equivalent, which is the case that most people are concerned about anyway.

We show that any open $G$ containing $E$ must satisfy $G \cap \mathbb{N}$ is co-finite in $\mathbb{N}$, from which we easily see that $\mu(G) = \infty$ and thus $\mu$ is not outer regular. To show this, we first note that $E$ is exactly the set of free ultrafilters $\mathcal{U}$ s.t. there exists $A \in \mathcal{U}$ with $\sum_{n \in A} \frac{1}{n+1} < \infty$. Indeed, if $\mathcal{U}$ satisfies the above condition, then the set $\Omega(A)$ of all ultrafilters (principal or free) that contain $A$ is an open neighborhood of $\mathcal{U}$, and $\Omega(A) \cap \mathbb{N} = A$, so by definition of $X$, we have $\mathcal{U} \in \Omega(A) \subset X$. Thus, $\mathcal{U} \in X \setminus \mathbb{N} = E$. Conversely, if $\mathcal{U} \in E \subset X$, then as $X$ is open and $\{\Omega(A)\}_{A \subset \mathbb{N}}$ is a basis of topology for $\beta\mathbb{N}$, we must have there is some $A \in \mathcal{U}$ s.t. the set $\Omega(A) \subset X$. But $\Omega(A)$ is also closed and thus compact, so by definition of $X$ there exists open $U_1, \cdots, U_k$ s.t. $\sum_{n \in U_i \cap \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{n+1} < \infty$ for all $i$ and $\Omega(A) \subset \bigcup_i U_i$. Thus,
$$\sum_{n \in A} \frac{1}{n+1} = \sum_{n \in \Omega(A) \cap \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{n+1} \leq \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{n \in U_i \cap \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{n+1} < \infty$$
Now, we proceed to show $E$ is dense in $\beta \mathbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{N}$. Again, as $\{\Omega(A)\}_{A \subset \mathbb{N}}$ is a basis of topology for $\beta\mathbb{N}$, it suffices to show for any $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\Omega(A) \setminus \mathbb{N}$ is nonempty, we have $\Omega(A) \cap E \neq \varnothing$. As $\Omega(A) \setminus \mathbb{N}$ is nonempty, $A$ is infinite. Then there is an infinite subset $B \subset A$ s.t. $\sum_{n \in B} \frac{1}{n+1} < \infty$. As $B$ is infinite, there is a free ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ containing $B$. By the description of $E$ obtained before, we see that $\mathcal{U} \in \Omega(A) \cap E$.
Now, as $G$ is open and $\mathbb{N} \subset \beta\mathbb{N}$ is dense, we must have $G \cap \mathbb{N}$ is dense in $G$. Thus, as $E \subset G$ and $\overline{E} = \beta\mathbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{N}$, we have $\overline{G \cap \mathbb{N}} \supset \beta\mathbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{N}$. But this implies $G \cap \mathbb{N}$ is co-finite in $\mathbb{N}$. Indeed, assume to the contrary that $\mathbb{N} \setminus G$ is infinite. Then there is a free ultrafilter $\mathcal{V}$ containing $\mathbb{N} \setminus G$. But $G \cap \mathbb{N} \subset \Omega(G \cap \mathbb{N})$ and the latter set is closed, so,
$$\mathcal{V} \in \beta\mathbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{N} \subset \overline{G \cap \mathbb{N}} \subset \Omega(G \cap \mathbb{N})$$
which means $G \cap \mathbb{N} \in \mathcal{V}$, contradicting the fact that $\mathbb{N} \setminus G \in \mathcal{V}$. This concludes the proof.

Thank you! That's a great answer.
